# PHP ltrim() and rtrim() functions

Tags: php, string

I need two functions that take a string and the number of characters to trim from the right and left side and return it. E.g.:

```
$str = "[test]";
$str = ltrim($str, 1); // Becomes 'test]'
$str = rtrim($str, 1); // Becomes 'test'
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function my_rtrim($str, $count) {
  return substr($str, 0, -$count);
}

function my_ltrim($str, $count) {
  return substr($str, $count);
}
```

See [substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Answer (score 6):

[`substr`](http://php.net/substr):

```
substr("abcdef", 0, -1);     // 'abcde'
substr("abcdef", 1);         // 'bcdef'
```

But that's not how `ltrim`, `rtrim` functions usually work. They operate with substrings and not indexes.

And obviously

```
substr('abcdef', 1, -1)
```

does what you want in one go.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [substr()](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) can do the job. Both the $start and $length arguments can be negative.

Comment: Can you [elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/834373/edit) in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)